# How do I get this information from the phone from android 10,11 java

Tags: java, android

How do I get this information from the phone (serial number , IMEI1 and 2) from android 10,11 or 8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not more possibile for a Normal App. Only System App can do System calls to get those information.

Non-System App needs Root Permissions to reach most of those.